# Error when upgrading EE - 'The update script failed without returning an error. Please contact tech support.'

Tags: add-on, upgrade

I was upgrading an EE install from 2.5.2 to 2.5.5. First of all, I updated all the add-ons to make sure they were the latest versions. Then I added the new EE files as per the [updating docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/update.html).

When running the upgrade, I got the following error message in a popup window after about 15 seconds:

```
The update script failed without returning an error. Please contact tech-support.
```

My hosting has plenty of memory (512mb) and execution time (60 seconds, though I even upgraded it to 600 seconds to rule it out as an issue) and has run dozens of upgrades before without any issues. I even tried upgrading from 2.5.2 to 2.5.3 instead, but got the same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To workaround the issue, I followed the advice from this [EE Support thread](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/216950/#1002041) by renaming the system/expressionengine/**third_party** folder to something else immediately before carrying out the upgrade. The upgrade then worked fine, and I renamed the third_party folder back afterwards and all was well.

The explanation for having to do this (from the same [EE support thread](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/216950/#1004307) as above) is that 'the updater is trying to run the update scripts of third-party modules, so moving them out of the way lets the updater complete, then you can update third-party modules after.'

I'm sure that all my add-ons were already updated before carrying out the EE upgrade, so I suspect I either missed one through human error (unlikely as I double-checked them), or there was a rogue add-on that was causing an issue with the EE update script (but it would have taken too much time to pin-point which one after the above workaround worked).

Answer (score 1):

Possibly safecracker_file. Gave me some further problems after removing/replacing third part folder.